# Jena Fuseki: Creation of Dataset does not work

Tags: java, jena, fuseki

I have Jena Fuseki database running on my localhost and I am trying to create a new dataset via the following Java code:

```
public static Dataset createDataset() {
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("http://localhost:3030/testDataset");

    return dataset;
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    createDataset();
}
```

My Java console shows the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBException: Does not exist: /Users/Philip/IdeaProjects/Squirrel_copy/http:/localhost:3030/testDataset/
at org.apache.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.error(DatasetBuilderStd.java:321)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.checkLocation(DatasetBuilderStd.java:139)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.build(DatasetBuilderStd.java:161)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.create(DatasetBuilderStd.java:90)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.StoreConnection.make(StoreConnection.java:208)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.StoreConnection.make(StoreConnection.java:215)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.transaction.DatasetGraphTransaction.<init>(DatasetGraphTransaction.java:65)
2018-01-21 17:08:03,092 [main] ERROR [o.a.j.info                    ] - <Does not exist: /Users/Philip/IdeaProjects/Squirrel_copy/http:/localhost:3030/testDataset/>
at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.TDBMaker._create(TDBMaker.java:55)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.TDBMaker.createDatasetGraphTransaction(TDBMaker.java:42)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBFactory._createDatasetGraph(TDBFactory.java:89)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDatasetGraph(TDBFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDataset(TDBFactory.java:55)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDataset(TDBFactory.java:51)
at org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.RDFSink.createDataset(RDFSink.java:43)
at org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.RDFSink.main(RDFSink.java:49)
```

The problem seems to be that the Java method tries to store the dataset in the location

```
/Users/Philip/IdeaProjects/Squirrel_copy/localhost:3030/testDataset/
```

with the unnecessary prefix of my local file system and I do not know how to remove this prefix.

Comment: How did you setup your JF database?

Comment: I have set it up via Docker in a .yml file. The database runs on my localhost and is accessible with the browser. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The method you've used seems somewhat under-documented, but if you look at a similar method here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/tdb/org/apache/jena/tdb/TDBFactory.html#createDataset-org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.Location-

with the signature

```
public static Dataset createDataset(org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.Location location)
```

then it suggests that this factory method expects a path to a directory in your file system, not the url on which your server is listening. The name of the `String`-type argument is `dir`, which also indicates that a path to a directory is expected.

If you want to create a new dataset on a running fuseki server, consider making use of fuseki's HTTP-based administration protocol, described here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html#datasets-and-services . This is not exactly a SPARQL query, and it uses http POST requests, but it should do what you want.

Comment: I have already tried to use the method you proposed. The result is the same. But do you know how I can create a dataset on a Jena DB that is running somewhere in the network? How can I send like a command to create a dataset ?

Comment: Do you want to submit some kind of SPARQL query analogous to SQL's "CREATE DATABASE" to a running fuseki server? I'm not sure whether this is supported, but my knowledge about Apache Jena might be somewhat outdated... If you want to create new datasets remotely, couldn't you cover this functionality by a little separate http-server which responds to post-requests with the creation of a new dataset? Maybe something useful here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html#datasets-and-services ? (updating answer)

Comment: Indeed - TDBFactory creates local TDB databases.

Comment: @AndyS could you also comment on the proposal to use HTTP POST's to Fuseki's administration api to create new TDB databases remotely? Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Andey's suggestion is correct.  Use the admin interface if you don't start the server with a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setup() throws IOException 
{ 
  ds = DatasetFactory.createTxnMem();
  server = FusekiServer.create().add("/ds", ds).build();
  server.start();
}
```